# Call to undefined function node_mass_update()

Tags: forms

In `hook_form_alter()`, I am using the following code.

```
if ($form_id == 'album_node_form') {
  $form['actions']['unpublish'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Unpublish'),
    '#submit' => array('az_alter_unpublish')
  );

  // …
}
```

In `az_alter_unpublish()`, I am using the following code.

```
function az_alter_unpublish($form, $form_state) {
  $nodes = array();
  // $nodes is an array of node IDs for the nodes I want to unpublish.
  node_mass_update($nodes, array(array('status' => 0)));

  // …
}
```

This returns a fatal error.

I read [the function documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.admin.inc/function/node_mass_update/7), but I can't find out the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to include the node.admin.inc file.

```
 module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.admin');
 node_mass_update($nodes,array(array('status' => 0)));
```

Comment: good solution , saved my time .vote +1